# AngularJS 1 form validation in the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

i have a problem with angulare code. I have made a small form structure with ng reapet . When i removed one of element every  element down of them are not show the "not valid" message . All up of them work fine but down of remove not showing info not given the false of this data-ng-show="Zhf.w{{key}}.$error.pattern" why ng show not taked false.

```
<form name="zhf" class="form-horizontal">
  <div data-ng-repeat="(key, i) in vm.items.Info | limitTo: (vm.NumberOfDays)">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="w{{key}}" name="w{{key}}" ng-model="vm.item[key].w" placeholder="0" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,10}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$/" required>
      <p style="color: #a94442" class="text-danger" data-ng-show="Zhf.w{{key}}.$error.pattern">
        <span>Not a valid number!</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " ng-click="vm.delete(key)">remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

 vm.delete = function(index) {
  vm.items.Info.splice(index, 1);
  vm.item.splice(index, 1);
  vm.NumberOfDays -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your ng-repeat section to validate form and sample is [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1dva925/7/)

```
     <form novalidate="novalidate" name="inputValidate">
        <div ng-repeat="field in fields.test">
        <div style="width:600px">
          <div ng-form name="validMe" style="width:58%;float:left">
              <input id="input{{$index}}" name="input{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="field.value" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,10}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$/" required> 
              <span style="color: #a94442" ng-show="validMe['input\{\{$index\}\}'].$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
              <span style="color: #a94442" ng-show="validMe['input\{\{$index\}\}'].$error.required ">Number Required!</span>
          </div>
          <div style="width:20%;float:left">
            <input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="delete($index)"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ye but the problem is when i remove one row my valid message is wrong for the nex val i think the taht error save the value . true this looks better but what about remove

Comment: It means you need to remove item from array and you also need to show error message? http://jsfiddle.net/x1dva925/5/ like this or you still want to show error message even after removing item from array? can you provide me sample?

Comment: no i wont to do it like thie
0[ Input  valu : aaa] <-- bad [remove button]
not valid info
1[ Input  valu : 11] <-- ok  [remove button]
2[ Input  valu : aaa] <-- bad  [remove button]
not valid info
i remove 0 and i got :
0[ Input  valu : 11] <-- ok  [remove button]
not valid info
1[ Input  valu : aaa] <-- bad  [remove button]

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your input plz check JSfiddle